# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo problemas de UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' num arquivo python e não estou conseguindo resolver.
Esse é o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 448, in <module>
    fileOriginal.sliceFile(url) #Separa os arquivos para evitar MemoryError
  File "file.py", line 188, in sliceFile
    line = fileOriginal.readline()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid
continuation byte
```

Ele ocorre no momento de ler um arquivo txt. O arquivo está codificado com UTF-8 without BOM. E eu não entendo por que dá esse erro. O erro ocorre na seguinte linha: "line = fileOriginal.readline()", conforme código a seguir:

Código:

```
for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(url): 
        contDec = 0 #Conta as declarações  
        contTempFiles = 0 #Conta os arquivo temporários                                            

        for file in files:                                                
            fileOriginal = open(os.path.join(url,file),encoding = "utf8")                                             

            endFile   = False
            contLines = 0
            contDec = 0
            cont    = 0
            line = ''
            while not 'ZZZZZ|' in line:                                     
                if cont == 0:
                    contTempFiles += 1                        

                    tempFile = open(os.path.join('separados',str(contTempFiles)+'_'+str(self.getFileName(file))+'.txt'),'w', encoding='utf-8')                                                
                line = fileOriginal.readline()#Erro nessa linha                                                
                if line[0:5] == '99999':
                    tempFile.write(line)
                    contDec += 1                                                                        
                if contDec <= 200000:                                                
                    tempFile.write(line)                        
                    cont += 1
                else:
                    contDec = 0
                    cont = 0
                    tempFile.close()                             
            fileOriginal.close()
```

Versão do Python: 3.4.0
Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?
Obrigado!

Comment: Cocola o erro na pergunta, vai facilitar ajudar.

Comment: Acrescentei o erro Ricardo

Comment: Eu tomei esse erro na hora de gerar logs no sistema, no meu caso as variáveis do linux não estavam setadas, mas era na escrita, uma coisa que pode estar acontecendo é que você está lendo os arquivos que tenham acentos, tenta ler um arquivo só com um texto simples e um com acentos. Aí posta o o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez da linha de código:

```
open(os.path.join(url,file), encoding = "utf8")
```

Experimenta colocar o seguinte:

```
path = os.path.join(url,file).decode("utf8")
open(path, encoding = "utf-8")
```

Não esquecer também colocar no início do código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Oi Rui, qual a diferença?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly a única diferença é o apostrofe: utf8 para utf-8

Comment: Também fiquei na dúvida de qual seria a diferença, pois esse código estava funcionando normalmente.

Comment: @RuiLima, fiz o que vc sugeriu, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: @fredsilva Editei a minha resposta, pode ser que o caminho para o ficheiro tenha caracteres especiais. Experimenta agora.

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver. Pegando o gancho da resposta do @Rui Lima. Substitui a linha:

```
fileOriginal = open(os.path.join(url,file), encoding = "utf8")
```

por:

```
fileOriginal = open(url+file,encoding = "utf-8")
```

Não sei por que motivo ao fazer o join dava o erro.
Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! 
Forte Abraço!